# docx4j export fo ignore doc stops

Tags: java, docx4j

I am trying to convert a docx file to pdf using docx4j-export-fo, here is my docx :
(doc stops in red)

[link to the docx file](https://ufile.io/leu5i)

[image]

and here the result of the conversion :

[link to the pdf file](https://ufile.io/nlm0e)

[image]

Doc stops are ignored and I don't know why and how to fix it

Here is the code I used to generated the file

```
        InputStream templateInputStream = new FileInputStream(templateName);
        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(templateInputStream);
        MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

        String outputfilepath = outputDir+outputName+".pdf";
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputfilepath);
        Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage,os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
```

I am using :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j-export-fo</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: See https://www.docx4java.org/forums/pdf-output-f27/exception-and-tabulator-problem-during-docx2pdf-conversion-t1264.html

Comment: my bad, ok thx ...